# AngularJS - Organizing large services & functions

Tags: angularjs, service, architecture, code-organization

I honestly can't think of ***the one way*** when it comes to the organization of my services.

I have a large service that defines a lot of methods, including one whose purpose it is to validate a large object. The functionality is quite complex, so I'd like to split the method up in bite-sized ones.

How should I do that? I can think of multiple ways to achieve this:

---

#### Creating a helper service whose only purpose it is to provide validation functionality

This could be the most elegant way, however it would bloat my application with another service

---

#### Keeping it in the current service, just split up the methods

This would lead to a very large validation method that lives amongst other ones, creating a vast service:

```
app.service('serv',function(){

    return{

        someFunc: function(){
            // ...
        },

        // some more functions

        _validate: function(options){

            // call each function defined below

            function a(){
                // ...
            }

             function b(){
                // ...
            }

             function c(){
                // ...
            }
        }

});
```

---

#### Defining private methods directly on the current service

Considering the above example, i could also define functions *a* - *c* directly on the service. Not quite elegant, too

So what is the best practice here?

Comment: What's the role of your service and to what feature does it relates? When asking this kind of question, you must provide real-word examples because only the domain will tell you how things should get organized.

Comment: Create sub-services and inject them into the main one. Break functionality apart into the sub-services. Map the functions the external callers will use into the one main module, and inject that in the other parts of the app.

Answer (score 0):

Please forgive my syntax or compialtion errors, as i am directly typing it here.

First things first i hope you meant factory and not service, as you don't return the object in a service.

Also, hope i understood your question correctly, so you dont want to inject helper services, but just organize the code in the same service, is that right?
One way i can think of is, wrap it under a IIFE, this would help in making all the variables and functions private

few tips, as a best practice, please avoid creating var app in window or global scope and referencing it everywhere else, it pollutes the global scope and secondly, it can create conflicts when your app gets bigger and you lose track of the variables created. if you need to get a module, use angular.module('yourAppName'), shown below.

```
(function(){

// define your variables or functions here, 
// All of them will be in the scope of the above function and
// outside functions cannot excess it or you can do the same inside the MyFactory function

angular.module('yourAppName').factory('myFactory', MyFactory);

function MyFactory(){
  var factory = {};  

  // some local variables
   var a, b, c;

 // some local functions,

    someFunc: function(){
            // ...
        },

    // some more functions

        _validate: function(options){

            // call each function defined below

            function a(){
                // ...
            }

             function b(){
                // ...
            }

             function c(){
                // ...
            }
    }

  // add the functions you want to expose to be called by the controllers or any objects where you have injected the factory. 
    factory.funcA = function(){   }

   return factory;
  }
})();
```